# Grails Camel Routing Plugin Not recognising sendMessage

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-camel

We have a project that we recently required the use of Camel in. This projects is a Groovy/Grails project and I have installed the Routing 1.4.1 plugin.

I then proceeded to create a new route as specified in the documentation which is shown below:

```
package some_package

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder

class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    def grailsApplication

    @Override
    void configure() {
        def config = grailsApplication?.config

        // example:
         from('seda:input.queue').to('stream:out')

    }
}
```

Then I proceeded to setup a call to this Route in one of my Controllers using the following '**sendMessage**' command:

```
//Camel Testing
def message = "This is some history"
sendMessage("seda:input.queue", message)
```

However when typing in the IDE the '**sendMessage**' method it does say '**Type Not Found**' which says to me maybe I am missing an import of something but according to the documentation this should be available to all Controllers and Services.

I added debug and the code hits the sendMessage line however does not get into the routing method.

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks

---

************UPDATE***********

---

So I installed everything again from scratch and used an older version of InteliJ and the simple example worked great.

Next I tried a more complex example of calling a service, however the app fails on startup, I have put the Service, Route and sendMessage data below:

**Route**

```
from("seda:input.queue").filter {
            it.in.body.contains("test")
        }.to("bean:TestService?method=printMsg")
```

**Service**

```
def printMsg(msg){
        println(msg)
    }
```

**sendMessage**

```
def myMessage = "this is a test message"
sendMessage("seda:input.queue", myMessage)
```

The error I get when running the app is below:

```
Error 2015-08-07 13:46:46,156 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugins.routing.processor.PredicateProcessor.to() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [bean:TestService?method=printMsg]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), getAt(java.lang.String), with(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
Message: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.plugins.routing.processor.PredicateProcessor.to() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [bean:TestService?method=printMsg]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), getAt(java.lang.String), with(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I hope you can help.

---

Update

---

Ok so i removed the filter piece and the application loaded.

However when the **sendMessage** got run I got the following error:

```
Message: No bean could be found in the registry for: TestService
```

I then tried to add the bean manually using the following code but still get the same error:

```
void configure() {
        def config = grailsApplication?.config

        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        registry.put("TestService", new TestService());
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);

        from("seda:input.queue").to("bean:TestService?method=printMsg")

    }
```

Comment: Your IDE (Eclipse?) might have trouble with dynamic method extensions. It shows an error because at compile time it can not find out what you added dynamically by injection. I think the sendMessage call is not the problem. But the perhaps the RoutBuilder is not called. Did you add it by scaffolding with `grails create-route Test`? Perhaps there is sophisticated registering which is only done by scaffolding. (Just a wild guess ;-) )

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and I did use the scaffolding method to create the Route. The route does get hit when the application first gets run, however when I use the sendMessage call it doesnt hit it. Do you know a way I can use Camel without using the Routing plugin?

Comment: It's correct; the route builder method should only be hit at startup. After the builder has run, the route is active. I used to implement camel routes for camel running in a karaf OSGI container. There I have CLI commands to list the routes and camel contexts. I will check the camel documentation for way to list the routes in a standalone/grails environment this evening when I will have more time ;-). (in about 8 hours; Germany) It has been a long time since I had worked with Grails.

Comment: That will be great and I really appreciate the help with this :)

Comment: Ok I got it working by using an older version of InteliJ, however another issue shown above :(

Comment: It's just a guess: try `filter({it.in.body.contains("test")}).to(`. Otherwise the .to() method will belong to the closure {...} after filter. And I think this closure has no method to() with a string parameter.

Comment: I removed the filter and it all loaded up ok, so then I went to the action to send the message ant it errors out saying: Message: No bean could be found in the registry for: TestService

Comment: So I tried to manually add the bean using the code above with no luck :S

Comment: any ideas how to get it to pick up the bean for the service?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use `ProducerTemplate` class as follows:

```
CamelContext context //the Camel Context running your routes
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate()
Object resultBody = template.sendBody("seda:input.queue", "Your body")
println(resultBody) //anything that your route puts in the body
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this however the CamelContext seems to be null and I am getting an error. Is there any reason this isn't listed in the documentation at  https://github.com/padcom/grails-routing

Comment: I have even tried downgrading to 1.4.0 of the routing plugin which has no affect

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this and it was down to a missname of the bean.

I found the error by listing all current beans in the context and then changing my call.

Thanks